# как работать с динамическими элементами на форме

Tags: javascript

Поставлена задача. Создать динамическое меню. Количество пунктов меню и их наименования приходит с json файла. Я сделала меню.Но теперь нужно отображать элементы на форме.Каждой вкладке меню соответствует форма с элементами которые указаны в `json` файле.

- На одной форме может быть только таблица. Эта форма соответствует
  одному пункту меню.
- На другой форме может быть таблица и листбокс и текстовое поле.

Из `json` файла узнаю что должно быть на форме.

Не понятно как это реализовать. Вот думаю может накидать на форму много элементов. А потом делать `ng-show = true` или `false`

Но что то плохой вариант мне кажется. А вдруг на форме, будет больше кнопок чем у меня в данный момент уже есть.

Как лучше сделать? Нет идеи.

Comment: _ng-show_ - вы используете ангуляр? приведите пример json по которому вы хотите построить форму и пример формы.

Comment: не знаю кто может ответить. Уже несколько дней думаю. Нет идеи.

Comment: Чтобы увидеть решение, для начала стоит четко описать задание.

Comment: Стоит начать с чего-то конкретного, на пример - с того, что написано в JSON, и для чего это все нужно.

Comment: _приведите пример json по которому вы хотите построить форму и пример формы, которая должна в итоге получиться._ а также, что вы используете? ангуляр? jQuery? что-то еще?

Comment: Пока мне не дали json файл. Я пишу фронтэнд.

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю в чем сложность. Вы вначале перебираете формы, в каждой форме вы перебираете элементы. В зависимости от типа элемента, вы рисуете конкретный элемент через ng-if.

```
<div ng-repeat="form in forms">
    <form>
        <fieldset ng-repeat="formItem in form">
            <input ng-if="formItem.type=='input' type="text" />
            <textarea ng-if="formItem.type=='textarea'></textarea>
            <select ng-if="formItem.type=='select'">...</select>
            ...
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Вот рабочий пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/Morulus/aqu6exov/